# jQuery form submit and html tag

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, reactjs, laravel

In my code, I am showing an image to the user by changing the src to

```
 $("#" + img_tag_id).attr('src', image.toDataURL());
```

how can I take the value of this file to input tag below:

HTML code:

```
   <input type="file" name="uploadNewImage">
```

I am using finecrop plugin

Answer (score 0):

Something like $('input[name='uploadNewImage']').attr('src', image.toDataURL());

Answer (score 0):

You should get the `src` attribute of the `input` element, since it should contain the **URL** that it displays:

`$('input[name='uploadNewImage']').attr('src', image.toDataURL());`